# trying to find duplicate usernames in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unique

i am trying to ensure that the username is unique when registering but im not sure how to do this

I've tried:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :username
```

but it doesnt work

it gives me this error:
undefined method 'validates_uniqueness_of' for `#<UsersController:0x6c4fd2>`

Any help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't specified where you have declared `validates_uniqueness_of`. It's a class method mixed into `ActiveRecord::Base`, so make sure you're declaring it inside of a model, not in a controller or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

`validates_uniqueness_of` should work, however you have to add unique index to the database column as well to avoid race conditions. This can be done via migration:

```
add_index :table_name, :column_name , :unique=> true
```

Check the `case_sensitive` option for [`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000086) as well.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be placed into the User *model* not the controller.